# What does -m yarn-cluster really mean?

Tags: apache-flink

I am new to Flink, I am using the following script to submit a batch mode Word Count to yarn.

```
./flink run -m yarn-cluster ../examples/batch/WordCount.jar
```

It is running in the yarn-cluster mode, so that the JM will run in one node of the yarn cluster.

So far so good, but I don't understand why I see the word dataset result printed on the console where I run the above script?

I am wondering what's the behavior of flink yarn-cluster, eg, if i run Dataset#collect, which process will get the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the results because JobManager sends them over to the client (cmd line script).

- Yarn-cluster mode means you start a separate cluster per execution.
- Yarn-session mode means you submit to a cluster that is already running.

You can check out more how the distributed runtime works [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/concepts/runtime.html#job-managers-task-managers-clients).